# How can I create new Dataframe columns using Pandas-equivalent of Excel's SUMIFS, COUNTIFS, AVERAGEIFS functions?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have the following `accounts.csv`:

```
CustomerID,InvoiceID,InvoiceDate,DueDate,SettledDate,InvoiceAmount,DaysToSettle,DaysLate
1,4564,29-03-2012,28-04-2012,25-04-2012,62.68,27,0
1,7897,15-05-2012,14-06-2012,28-05-2012,77.19,13,0
1,8749,21-05-2012,20-06-2012,04-06-2012,51.65,14,0
1,4189,16-06-2012,16-07-2012,04-07-2012,64.47,18,0
2,1353,12-02-2012,13-03-2012,28-02-2012,28.21,16,0
2,4898,01-03-2012,31-03-2012,17-04-2012,48.65,47,17
2,7994,20-03-2012,19-04-2012,08-04-2012,103.64,19,0
2,4652,01-07-2012,31-07-2012,17-07-2012,42.25,16,0
2,1561,01-09-2012,01-10-2012,23-09-2012,69.55,22,0
```

I can do

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(str(x), '%d-%m-%Y')
df = pd.read_csv('accounts.csv', parse_dates=['InvoiceDate','DueDate','SettledDate'], date_parser=dateparse)
df.sort_values(by=['CustomerID', 'InvoiceDate'])

df
```

to read it into a dataframe:

```
   CustomerID  InvoiceID InvoiceDate    DueDate  InvoiceAmount SettledDate  DaysToSettle  DaysLate
0           1       4564  2012-03-29 2012-04-28          62.68  2012-04-25            27         0
1           1       7897  2012-05-15 2012-06-14          77.19  2012-05-28            13         0
2           1       8749  2012-05-21 2012-06-20          51.65  2012-06-04            14         0
3           1       4189  2012-06-16 2012-07-16          64.47  2012-07-04            18         0
4           2       1353  2012-02-12 2012-03-13          28.21  2012-02-28            16         0
5           2       4898  2012-03-01 2012-03-31          48.65  2012-04-17            47        17
6           2       7994  2012-03-20 2012-04-19         103.64  2012-04-08            19         0
7           2       4652  2012-07-01 2012-07-31          42.25  2012-07-17            16         0
8           2       1561  2012-09-01 2012-10-01          69.55  2012-09-23            22         0
```

---

On Excel/LibreOffice, it's very easy to add new columns using functions `COUNTIFS`, `SUMIFS`, and `AVERAGEIFS` based on two or more IF conditions (e.g. CustomerID equal to current row, InvoiceDate less than current row, DaysLate greater than 0).

[image: libreoffice_screenshot]

where `I2` is `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2, C:C, "<"&C2, H:H,">0")`, `J2` is `=SUMIFS(E:E,A:A,A2,C:C,"<"&C2)` and `K2` is `=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(E:E,A:A,A2,C:C,"<"&C2),0)`.

---

I'm very new to Pandas and I can't seem to figure out how to create new columns based on multiple conditions. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a boolean mask representing the cases where you do want to fill. Then you can selectively fill based on that mask.

Suppose this is your dataframe :

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': list(range(10)),
    'b': list(range(-5, 5)),
})
```

You want to build a column `c` based on the values of `a` and `b`.

```py
# this is an example condition
mask = (df['a'] < df['b']) | (df['a'] <= 1) 


df['c'] = None
func = lambda x: x**2
df.loc[mask, 'c'] = 42 # cases where your condition is True
df.loc[~mask, 'c'] = func(df['a']) # cases where it's False
```

Essentially, you first build a conditional selection, then apply some function to the result.

To get the rows where a column is null, use `df[col].isnull()`. To sum, use `.sum()`.

Comment: In this case, you used a constant value (<= 1) in the mask. How can I refer to a specific column in each row?

Comment: @5areductase if you look at how I built `mask` there are two parts that get combined with an or. The part on the left `df['a'] < df['b']` compares the current row of `a` to the current row of `b`.

Comment: If you look at my Excel equations, I'm comparing a value from the current row to those of previous rows,  instead of column A vs column B. I thought there would be `groupby` involved somewhere.

Comment: You can groupby or iterate over it